# Since I cannot answer to the last Top question, is ok to create a new Post to answer that question?

Tags: discussion

Rerefence: [How can we justify the use of logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22103/how-can-we-justify-the-use-of-logic)

Is quiet interesting question: All areas of all kind of subject create and have their own logic content that is used to defend many things about that specific subject. To the Police the Law is the reasons and even if they don't use too much logic to defend the Law ( because even the Law it self have Flaw's ) people use it because is the source of their own knowledge. ( which make all the sense in the world ) > Philosophy is how to think rationally some subject so we can prove that subject is true or false, by the way we think. We know many philosophers have different opinions about their own interpretation of some specific subject that others that have the same knowledge level, have. But we need to use logic because all creations in this world are the result of "Fantasy" + "Logic" that result in the "application".

Therefor (1+1=1 OR 3) >> Tao / Dao << Is all about Logic <<

Linguistic structures are similar to programming languages or maybe we should say that is the inverse ( programming languages are silimar to verbal languages ), and that is true, because those who did develop a programming languages did develop by comparing the way he/she thinks. Once again ( using Logic ) which is the best way where many can read the same message. By the fantastic perspective, we have all the concepts in the world about spirituality, gods, souls, spirits, etc... I think in more than 20 centuries, they did fight for what each believes in their own "fantastic" way, where Logic cannot be introducted easly. Is possible, but is difficult because is a abstract concept.. therefor the catolics did impose their power to express the "unique" God. By Logic if there is only one God ( we don't need to discuss other gods ) >> Even with bad examples in History, they made the best choice ( using logic )

What is intuitive to philosophers is not for a scientist or biologist...

Comment: No it's not okay.

Comment: As people did hack Time to "talk" with "machines", since they are "a reflection of interaction", as we are... In need to participate!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can not answer the question?

Comment: @Conifold At least four deleted answers.

Comment: @curiousdannii I still see the box at the bottom where I can post an answer. Is there a rule somewhere about threads with four+ deleted answers? Or users with four+ deleted answers?

Comment: @Conifold See my answer

Comment: It bothers me that someone upvoted this question.

Comment: @Conifold is the reputation "limits" :D

Answer (score 4):

You have been automatically blocked from creating questions or answers due to several low quality posts that have been deleted.

This is a standard reaction by the system and one which we cannot lift. Circumventing it would be a violation of our rules and be met with suspension. For more information about this and a guide about what you can do about it, see [this site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans).

Basically, you should try to improve your existing posts instead. Even if they are deleted, you can edit them and flag them in order to inform us about the improvements and ask for undeletion.

Comment: :) Yeah You are right.. I am trying to improve my self on it, but you know... I am just the brain snail ... while Time... Thank You!